# How to get the text of each item in class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many structures like this:

```
<div class="passTab" data-name="">
   <div class="logoTab" title="" onclick="openWindow('')">
       <img class="logoImg" src="./">
       <label class="title"></label>
   </div>
   <ul class="noteList">
       <li><label class="l_mail note">some_text1</label></li>
       <li><label class="l_nick note">some_text2</label></li>
       <li><label class="l_pass note">some_text3</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And i need to get text of each item in class separately.

I used:

```
$('.note').text()
```

and

```
$('.note').toArray($(this).text())
```

Comment: You could use `$('.note').map(function() {return $(this).text()}).get();`

Comment: not jQuery... but: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.note')].map(elm => elm.innerText.trim())`

Answer (score -1):

What is your problem? You can simply create an array and just add everything in a loop. For example with a loop from jQuery library:

```
let arr = [];
$('.note').each(()=>{
   arr.push(this.text());
});
```

Or something like that...

Comment: I've made the corrections, I was just writing a quick answer. It's an example, not a solution. You can leave it inside the loop and just return a value, it doesn't really matter

Comment: Well, it should be `(i, elm) => arr.push($(elm).text())` if you are going to use arrow fn

Answer (score -2):

Just loop through the notes using .each() or .map()

https://api.jquery.com/each/
https://api.jquery.com/map/

```js
//Loop through notes and do something
$('.note').each((index, note) => console.log($(note).text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="passTab" data-name="">
   <div class="logoTab" title="" onclick="openWindow('')">
       <img class="logoImg" src="./">
       <label class="title"></label>
   </div>
   <ul class="noteList">
       <li><label class="l_mail note">some_text1</label></li>
       <li><label class="l_nick note">some_text2</label></li>
       <li><label class="l_pass note">some_text3</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```